# IP whitelist a single php file with nginx but still run php

Tags: php, nginx

I have a pretty typical php5-fpm setup like so:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/home/gfd-dev/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

and I just want to just block 1 file by ip address,  but then php doesn't run

```
location ^~ /script_to_hide.php {
  allow 100.100.100.100; 
  deny all;
}
```

Do I put the whole php$ params in both or is there a another way to do this to just tell php to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ^~ /secret_functions/ {
    allow 100.100.100.100; 
    deny all;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

fastcgi_params

```
    ...
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/home/gfd-dev/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
```

P.S.

Nginx iterate through each location based on [the following logic](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

```
location = / {
    [ configuration A ]
}

location / {
    [ configuration B ]
}

location /documents/ {
    [ configuration C ]
}

location ^~ /images/ {
    [ configuration D ]
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    [ configuration E ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mikhailov, I was able to do this also, but what I think I'm trying to figure out is if I have to do this every time I want to make a directive, do I have to put in the php bit, it can get pretty cluttered if I just keep copying and pasting the same bit of code.  Is there some sort of inclution way to write it?  or might a directory be better at allowing the .php to run?